# SQL syntax explanation (CAST, INSERT, DATE)

Tags: sql, db2

This is for educational purposes but could someone please explain what the below syntax is doing?

```
CAST(INSERT(CHAR(DATE(DB2_RID), USA), 3, 3, '') AS CHAR(10)) AS MONTH
```

I have googled the functions and understand most of it but I'm just curious on the process of turning a value of 2017-12-18-13.21.04.442956 into 12/2017

The data type for DB2_RID is a timestamp.

So I understand that CAST is converting the inner value into a character of 10. I guess my confusion is how did it know it was a date and to not include the day of the month such as 12/01/2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `DATE(DB2_RID)` = cast the timestamp as a date: `2018-12-18`
- `CHAR(..., USA)` = cast the date to a string using US format: `'12/18/2017'`
- `INSERT(..., 3, 3, '')` = replace the 3 characters starting at position 3 with
  an empty string, i.e. remove `/18`: `'12/2017'`
- `CAST(... AS CHAR(10))`: quite stupid, why not a CHAR(7)?: `'12/2017   '`

I can't test it, but this seems to be a complicated way to write:

```
TO_CHAR(DB2_RID, 'MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: im not sure why CHAR(10) was set to 10. Another analyst who does not work here created the syntax and i was trying to decipher the meaning of it. I will attempt the syntax you provided and let you know what the results are. Thank you.

Comment: i attempted your syntax and received this error:  BIC00004. DAL01008. An error occurred while accessing the database.
FORMAT STRING %m/%y IS NOT VALID FOR THE TO_CHAR FUNCTION. SQLCODE=-20447, SQLSTATE=22007, DRIVER=4.17.29; THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=4.17.29.

Comment: i adjusted the syntax to -  TO_CHAR (DB2_RID, 'MM/YYYY') and i got the expected result. Thank you for this solution!

Comment: Btw, a more common way to encode year&month would be `'2018/12'` or `'201812'`, i.e. leading year which allows sorting & filtering. Or store as an integer `210812` = `year(DB2_RID)*100 + month(DB2_RID)`

Answer (score 1):

@Dnoeth explain you your part of SQL Code. It Can be replaced by

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT(DB2_RID, 'MM/YYYY')
```